# How to use tailwindcss transitions in nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js, transition, tailwind-css

So I was trying to use tailwindcss transistions into my nuxt application, I wanted to basically animate the modal using the classnames provided by vue transitions

Here's my code for the Modal.vue file

```html
<template>
  <!-- This example requires Tailwind CSS v2.0+ -->
  <transition
    name="modal"
    enter-class="ease-out duration-300 opacity-0"
    enter-to-class="opacity-100"
    leave-class="opacity-100"
    leave-to-class="ease-out duration-200 opacity-0"
  >
    <div class="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto">
      <div
        class="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0"
      >
        <!--
      Background overlay, show/hide based on modal state.

      Entering: "ease-out duration-300"
        From: "opacity-0"
        To: "opacity-100"
      Leaving: "ease-in duration-200"
        From: "opacity-100"
        To: "opacity-0"
    -->
        <div
          class="fixed inset-0 transition-opacity"
          aria-hidden="true"
          @click="handleCloseModal"
        >
          <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. -->
        <span
          class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen"
          aria-hidden="true"
          >&#8203;</span
        >
        <!--
      Modal panel, show/hide based on modal state.

      Entering: "ease-out duration-300"
        From: "opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
        To: "opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
      Leaving: "ease-in duration-200"
        From: "opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
        To: "opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
    -->
        <div
          class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full"
          role="dialog"
          aria-modal="true"
          aria-labelledby="modal-headline"
        >
          <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
            <div class="sm:flex sm:items-start">
              <div
                class="mx-auto flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-red-100 sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 sm:w-10"
              >
                <!-- Heroicon name: outline/exclamation -->
                <svg
                  class="h-6 w-6 text-red-600"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    d="M12 9v2m0 4h.01m-6.938 4h13.856c1.54 0 2.502-1.667 1.732-3L13.732 4c-.77-1.333-2.694-1.333-3.464 0L3.34 16c-.77 1.333.192 3 1.732 3z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div class="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
                <h3
                  class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900"
                  id="modal-headline"
                >
                  Deactivate account
                </h3>
                <div class="mt-2">
                  <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">
                    Are you sure you want to deactivate your account? All of
                    your data will be permanently removed. This action cannot be
                    undone.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-red-600 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-red-500 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm"
              @click="handleCloseModal"
            >
              Deactivate
            </button>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="mt-3 w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-white text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm"
            >
              Cancel
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script> 
export default {
  methods: {
    handleCloseModal() {
      this.$emit("close-modal");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I tried to work with regular transitions by adding it to the name and it worked but this seems to have and Issue

Thanks to the kind soul in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out myself, somehow changing the duration to the enter to class made it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use "enter-active-class" instead "enter-class"
Here the solution that work for me:

```
 <transition
           enter-active-class="duration-300 ease-out opacity-0"
           enter-to-class="opacity-100"
           leave-active-class="duration-200 ease-in"
           leave-class="opacity-100"
           leave-to-class="opacity-0"
 >
```